# In current Scala, is there a cleaner way to do the "lazy constructor pattern"

Tags: scala, constructor, lazy-evaluation

The nearest thing to

```
case class Foo(lazy next: Foo)
```

that I have been able to come up with is

```
class Foo(_next: =>Foo) {
    lazy val next = _next
}
object Foo {
    def apply(next: =>Foo) = new Foo(next)
    def unapply(foo: Foo) = Some(foo.next)
}
```

I found a listed issue [add lazy parameters](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-240) so I guess it will be added
someday. In the meantime, does anyone know a cleaner trick than the above?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that your `unapply` method isn't lazy, so trying to pattern match a `Foo` into another `Foo` will result in `next` being evaluated, which you may not want.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon That's a good point. I suppose the only way to make it lazy would be to add indirection, as in `def unapply(foo: Foo) = Some(() => foo.next)` ?

Comment: That seems to work. I was just avoiding using `unapply` for my lazy case classes. In that case, though, you need to explicitly call the function, like `case Foo(n) => Foo(doSomething(n()))`. At that point, it might be better to use `Need`. (Also, if you go the `Need` route, you can define an overloaded constructor for `Foo` that takes a call-by-name parameter and turns it into a `Need`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `scalaz.Need`? This was suggested to me in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188032/192247).

```
scala> case class Foo(next: Name[Foo])
defined class Foo

scala> lazy val x: Foo = Foo(Need(y)); lazy val y: Foo = Foo(Need(x))
x: Foo = <lazy>
y: Foo = <lazy>

scala> x.next.flatMap(_.next).value eq x
res61: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I suppose it is debatable whether this is cleaner. But the messiness is in a different place, so it is a useful alternative either way.

Comment: @Owen, that's the approach I have resorted to in past. I too would like to have first class language support.