# call-by-name parameter

Tags: scala, types

anybody can give me explain how to work call-by-name inside of the scala compiler?
Syntactic shortcut for that method will be such: arg: `=>Int` will be transformed to `arg: () => Int` and captures the passed parameter to the function, how a closure?
i.e real type of call-by-name parameter such: `Function0[_]`?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? The question isn't clear.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Hi. Let's assume that i want something like such: `def foo(i: =>Int): Either[Int,Function1[here need the type of 'call-by-name' parameter,Either[_,_]]]`. **How can i write it?** The question of purely hypothetical...

Answer (score 4):

Call-by-name parameters, as you yourself have discovered, desugar down to `Function0[A]`. They do not have a first class support, and thus no different type as such.

You can kind of achieve something along those lines using `Name` from Scalaz. For that, see the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188032/192247).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, yes the syntax `=> Int` is essentially a lightweight syntax for anonymous parameterless function `() => Int`, that is represented by type `Function0[Int]` in Scala. Furthermore, within the VM by-name parameters translate to inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

A by-name parameter's type is parameterless method (see @som-snytt's comment). It cannot be used on Scala 2.x anywhere *except* on a method's parameter type.

You can use a `Function0` in place of a parameter that is being passed by-name, but that has different semantics.

Comment: It is a "method type", per spec.

Comment: @som-snytt I wonder if that's a new thing. I'm pretty sure I spent a long time with the spec back in 2012, and "by name" was not considered a type a the time. Do you have a reference in the spec?

Comment: I had issues with both by-name and repeated params, esp around overloading. Method type is https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#method-types and by-name https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#by-name-parameters says plainly it is a "parameterless method type". Sorry to resurrect an old answer; your words carry special weight. The other response also treats it as mere sugar. I wonder if 2.8 or 2.9 was in use.

Comment: @som-snytt I wouldn't have been surprised if it had been 2.7! I'm guessing 2.8, though it seems 2.9 was already around? I'm not sure the spec was updated, though. The wording of the special case on the method type does look rather unfamiliar to me. It does seem to be something added afterwards, but, hey, I might just have been wrong.